# iphone programming objective-c : viewDidLoad() execution

Tags: iphone, viewdidload, tabbarcontroller

my application have a tabbarcontroller with 4 view Controllers.

Its called here :

```
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

The view controller that appear first in the tabbar is called "Home"
I want when opening the app to load the viewcontroller and not just the tabbar. It is possible? I want the ViewDidLoad() method from my Home view controller to be called. Thanks

Comment: In Objective-C it is uncommon to refer to a method by appending parentheses. The name of the method in this case is just `viewDidLoad`. To disambiguate between class and instance methods, prepend a `+` or a `-` respectively (i.e. `-viewDidLoad`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is based on a TabBarController, you want to load the viewControllers into your TabBarController and then add the TabBarControllers view to the window. For example:

```
FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
SecondViewController *svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fvc,svc,nil];
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[fvc release];
[svc release];
```

where tabBarController is an instance variable and property. The first tab to display when your app launches will be the first one you load into the array. In this case it is fvc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just go as usual load the first viewController (use it as Home page )and handle the tabbar hidden property (where you want to show or hide it).